# Unable to run kafka connect datagen inside kafka connect docker image

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to run kafka datagen connector inside kafka-connect container and my kafka resides in AWS MSK using : https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen/blob/master/Dockerfile-confluenthub.

I am using kafdrop as a web browser for kafka broker (MSK). I don't see Kafka datagen generating any test messages.
Is there anything other configuration I need to do except installing the kafka-datagen connector

Also, how can I check inside confluentinc/kafka-connect image what topics are created and whether messages are consumed or not?

Dockerfile looks like :

```
ARG BASE_PREFIX=confluentinc 
ARG CONNECT_IMAGE=cp-kafka-connect

FROM $BASE_PREFIX/$CONNECT_IMAGE:6.1.0

ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"

RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.4.0
```

```
docker exec 51e32e20b292 bash -c 'echo $CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH'                                           
shows : /usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components
```

```
[appuser@88db8385b575 ~]$ ls -la /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 1 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 21:19 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root    root    4096 Feb  4 21:10 ..
drwxr-xr-x 6 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 18:00 confluentinc-kafka-connect-datagen
```

```
[appuser@88db8385b575 ~]$ ls -la /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-datagen/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 6 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 18:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 21:19 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 18:00 assets
drwxr-xr-x 4 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 18:00 doc
drwxr-xr-x 2 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 18:00 etc
drwxr-xr-x 2 appuser appuser 4096 Mar 26 18:00 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 appuser appuser 1380 Mar 26 18:00 manifest.json
```

Docker logs :

```
docker logs 51e32e20b292 | grep "DatagenConnector"  
        
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
```

Comment: Please show what configurations you have so far and your container logs... And you don't need to enter the container to check topic creation

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer Edited the question  with configuration and other information .

Comment: Did you actually POST a connector config? It's not running by default. Are there errors in the logs?

Comment: I just added in the dockerfile and ran RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.4.0 inside the dockerfile. Nothing else. No error logs .

Comment: How can I do a POST inside the container. I want to make everything containerised because my broker resides in MSK and container will reside in Fargate . @OneCricketeer

Comment: Okay and make that curl request dockerised right ?

Comment: Right also 8083 should point to the CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS right ?

Comment: Yes bootstrap server uses 9092. so i should make localhost:8083/connectors right where kafka-connect and kafka datagen resides?

Comment: You could also use the Landoop Kafka Connect UI since you're using kafdrop

Comment: isnt the kafka connect ui same as kafdrop ? My setup is in place, I just want to send messages to my broker and check in the UI. Do you have any recommendation from where I can send messages to broker and check topics and messages in UI ? @OneCricketeer

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer. My kafka-connect always says localhost:8083 connection failed to localhost . Any idea what could be the reason ? Do I need to add rest.port=8083 in connect-distributed.properties ?

Comment: That should be the default value. If you're running in Fargate, you might need to adjust the rest.listeners configurations

Comment: right now everything is commented in connect-distributed.properties except plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components . In this case then I need to uncomment rest.listeners configuration too right ?

Comment: You shouldn't be editing that file directly. It's templated from the Docker environment variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just added in the dockerfile and ran RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen:0.4.0 inside the dockerfile. Nothing else. No error logs .

That alone doesn't run the connector, only makes it available to the Connect API. Notice the curl example in the docs  https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-datagen#run-connector-in-docker-compose

So, expose port 8083 and make the request to add the connector, and make sure to add all the relevant environment variables when you're running the container